# Doctrine/Symfony - I have some errors. Something wrong with my relations

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I always get an exception with my entities. I tried to play with them. I checked on google which relation is the most appropriate for my entities... But I couldn't find the best configuration.

I'm making a website where you can create some albums.

A user can have multiple albums.So I have an entity Album and I have inside a user property :

```
/**
* Album
*
* @ORM\Table(name="album")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\AlbumRepository")
*/

class Album
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/** 
 ** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 ** @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false) 
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="creationDate", type="datetime")
 */
private $creationDate;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modificationDate", type="datetime")
 */
private $modificationDate;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Picture", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="album")
 */
 private $pictures;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->creationDate = new \Datetime();
    $this->modificationDate = new \Datetime();
}
 // Get and set
}
```

However, When a user subscribe on the website, I create a default album called Upload that I want to keep in the user class.

This is what I tried to do :

```
/**
* User
*    
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser  
{
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
 protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 protected $albumUpload;

 // Get and set
}
```

I have this error :
`Undefined index: album in /Users/Sandro/sites/moodress-website/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1608.` This error appears directly when I serialize any entity that has a user object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error:

```
'Undefined index: album'
```

results from this annotation in the Album class.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Picture",
 *      cascade={"persist"}, 
 *      mappedBy="album"
 *  )
 */
```

I have set mappedBy to album but there is no $album property in my Picture class.

I did add this to my Picture class and clear my cache.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *      targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album",
 *      inversedBy="pictures"
 *  )
 */
protected $album;
```

It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the association annotation of the $albumUpload property in the User class.

Doctrine assumes that you have a $album property in your Album entity when you use a `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album")` association in your User entity.

Try

```
/** 
 ** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="albums")
 ** @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false) 
 */
private $user;
```

in your Album entity and

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\AlbumBundle\Entity\Album", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 */
 protected $albums;
```

in your User entity. In addition please add `$this->albums = new ArrayCollection()` to User::__construct().

Now if you want to add and **keep** a default album for users you should implement this somewhere in your business logic. You could figure out a way to identify the default album in your collection of albums and prevent deletion especially for this item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find any correlation between serializing entities having a user object and your error... Could you please post the code that causes the error and the entities you are using in this context? The BasicEntityPersister should not be triggered in any case when using serialize()...